# Debug symbols for libgcc in MSYS2

Tags: debugging, gcc, debug-symbols, msys2

I use the MSYS2 `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` group to build my code and stack traces would be more useful if I had debug symbols for the standard library `libgcc`.

I have searched on the package manager and Google, but can't work out how to get debugging symbols for the standard library. I would expect a `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-devel` or `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-dbgsym package`.

Would I have to compile gcc from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need build GCC yourself with debug enabled. MSYS2 provide only release builds